# Can I upload a wav file to twilio and get it transcribed?

Tags: twilio, speech-to-text

We currently use twilio to send out SMS messages to our employees on the field.  I see that twilio has a transcription service.  We have many voicemails in-house which are wav files that needs to converted to text.  I was looking at a way of uploading these voicemails into twilio and get it transcribed.  Would it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Are these voicemails actually connected in any way to Twilio? It sounds like you have just some regular WAV audio files and are wondering if you can use the Twilio transcription API to convert audio files to text?

If this is the case then it looks like you might be better off using a more pure transcription-as-a-service API.

Maybe something like [Speechmatics](https://speechmatics.com/)?

If these audio files are in fact from a Twilio received call then it looks like you can use the Twilio Transcription API to receive the text. Check out their API docs page: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/transcription